# radius of convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {x^n \over {n^\sqrt n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Trying to find the raduis of convergence of this series
$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {x^n \over {n^\sqrt n}}$

ratio test seemed hard to apply. With the root test
$$
\limsup \left|{x^n \over {n^\sqrt n}}\right|^{1/n}
 = |x-0| \limsup \left|{1 \over n^{1/\sqrt n}}\right|
 = 0.
$$
I don't know what that means exactly. Does it mean (if correct) that the radius of convergence is $0$?

Comment: You should take the coefficient and apply the root test. And the convergence radius should be $R=\frac{1}{\lim\sup\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}}$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\lim \left(n^{\sqrt n}\right)^{1/n}
 = \lim n^{1/\sqrt n}
 = \lim \exp \left(\frac {\ln n} {\sqrt n}\right)
 =1
$$
so $|a_n|^{1/n} \to |x|$. The radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You could even use the ratio test
$$a_n=n^{-\sqrt{n}}\implies \log(a_n)=-\sqrt{n} \log (n)$$
$$\log(a_n)-\log(a_{n+1})=\sqrt{n+1} \log (n+1)-\sqrt{n} \log (n)$$ Now, using Taylor expansions
$$\log(a_n)-\log(a_{n+1})=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \left(1+\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(n\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=e^{\log(a_n)-\log(a_{n+1})}=1+\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}\log (n)}{\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$